# Why is my player slow when walking vertically?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging

I've recently been working on a top-down 2D game but the last few days, I've been getting a weird bug where the player walks really slow when walking down sometimes. The game is still really small, so it shouldn't lag whatsoever. Walking right or left is smooth, and all the enemies move fine, but when the player walks down, it gets really slow. Also, sometimes when an enemy hits the player, it'll essentially freeze you in place, or make you even slower. I'm honestly not sure if it's lag or a bug, but it happens about 80% of the time. When I created a WebGL build, the problem sometimes doesn't happen, but when you reload the page, there's about a 50/50 chance that it'll be bugged again. I don't think there's any code that's making it do this. I tried adding a new "spin attack" for my player, but I decided to scrap it, and I deleted all the code. Only then is when the problem started. Also, I shared the build to another computer, and the bug always happened on that computer. I haven't been able to find any consistencies, it seems to just happen at random, but obviously I can't just accept that. It feels like some problem with the Rigidbody, but I never even changed my movement script, so I am clueless.

Here is some of my movement script. I know it's pretty elementary, but I'm new to coding, so if there's a better way to do it feel free to share.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && GetComponent<PlayerActions>().canSwing == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(StopMoving());
        }

        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

void FixedUpdate()
    {
        playerRb.MovePosition(playerRb.position + movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

IEnumerator StopMoving()
    {
        frozen = true;
        speed = 0f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.4f);
        frozen = false;
        speed = 2.5f;
    }
```

Here's the code for slime (enemy) collisions:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        // Player takes damage when hit
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            player.GetComponent<Health>().health--;
            AddContactKB();
        } // Slimes repel each other
        else if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Slime")
        {
            StartCoroutine(SetMaxSpeed());
            Vector2 kbDirection = transform.position - collision.transform.position;
            kbDirection.Normalize();
            slimeRb.AddForce(kbDirection * 3, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
```

Player Rigidbody:
[image: Player Rigidbody]

Comment: Since you aren't sure where the problem comes, and I assume you cant revert back to before you deleted the new "spin attack" code, can you share the player Rigidbody component as a screen shot? and also share a snippet of the relevant player movement code and OnColision code from enemy and player? otherwise will be hard to help.

Comment: A starter would be showing us your code for the movement I guess ....

Comment: @BarretoFreekhealer I changed my question to include all of the things you wanted. Maybe there's another player controller script I can use?

Comment: @derHugo I added some more relevant information. Hope it helps a little

Comment: you should create a variable for `GetComponent<PlayerActions>()` fetch it in the start or when you can, then use that variable in the update, same with `player.GetComponent<Health>()`. Not so relevant, and I cant verify, you can simplify `collision.gameObject.tag == "Player"`  with  `collision.CompareTag("Player")`. Now I dont see why the behaviour you describe would happen, you could try set the `movement` axis manually to debug, and in the collision could it be this method `AddContactKB();` that causes the freeze?

Comment: @BarretoFreekhealer Thanks for the suggestion, but AddContactKb() adds knockback to the slime, not the player. I think I'll just try to use a different method for moving the player. Do you have any suggestions?